# Wordpress | Взять и вывести имя категории по описанию категории

Tags: php, wordpress

Использую этот код для вывода имени категории (по ярлыку):

```
$idObj = get_category_by_slug('products');
$id = $idObj->term_id;
echo get_cat_name($id);
```

Но нужно взять и вывести имя категории по ее описанию (description).

Как взять и вывести имя категории по **описанию** категории?

Comment: Взять и вывести )) 
if (category_description() == 'бла-бла') {echo get_cat_name();}
Код не проверял, это уж вы сами...

Comment: Нельзя так просто взять и вывести ))

Answer (score 4):

Получить можно из базы из таблицы `term_taxonomy`, но тут вопрос зачем это нужно....скорее всего у вас проблемы в логике вашего кода.

```
$description = 'some description';
global $wpdb;

$term_id = $wpdb->get_var(
    $wpdb->prepare(
        'SELECT term_id FROM . $wpdb->term_taxonomy . WHERE description = %s', $description
    )
);
if ( $term_id ) {
    $term = get_term( $term_id );
    echo $term->name;
}
```